# How to display object's properties on the front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have an object that I save like this in my controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

and when it comes time to display it, using HAML, I am trying to do something like this:

```
-@user.first_name
```

but nothing gets rendered.  What am I doing wrong? I saw many examples using the @user in a form.  Should I do that even though I don't have a form to create in this case? Or I also saw a lot of places that use the :some_var notation, but I am not certain which approach applies in this case.

Comment: `User.find` does not save, it *finds*.

Comment: yeah but I saved it to the @user variable.  Or that didn't save it?

Comment: That's dangerous terminology. I'd say, "you set a variable `@user` to a value returned from `User.find`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use equal sign instead of minus

```
= @user.first_name
```

Minus does not output anything to the HTML, it ignores returned value. Equal sign does emit returned value to the HTML.

Comment: This worked! I will accept it in 11 min when SO allows it.  Thank you Sergio.

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between the minus and the equal sign when displaying?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to show us the relevant code. But my first thought:

- did you add `@user = User.find(params[:id])` to the controller show action?

Comment: He didn't, it was my first thought about what could be wrong. But you are correct, it was the minus sign. Didn't even notice the difference on my zoomed out "low res" iPad :)